# Is octupole moment traceless?

Tags: electrostatics, tensor-calculus, classical-electrodynamics, multipole-expansion

I derived expressions for quadrupole $\Theta_{ij}$ and octupole moment $\Omega_{ijk}$:
$$\Theta_{ij} = \frac{1}{2}\int dV \rho(\mathbf{r}')\left[3r'_ir'_j - r'^2\delta_{ij} \right],$$
$$\Omega_{ijk} = \frac{1}{2}\int dV \rho(\mathbf{r}')\left[5r'_i r'_j r'_k - r'^2(\delta_{ij}r'_k + \delta_{ik}r'_j + \delta_{jk}r'_i) \right].$$
I can clearly see that $\Theta_{ij}$ is traceless, but I do not see how $\Omega_{ijk}$ could be traceless on any two indices. In this book [Relativistic Electronic Structure Theory - Fundamentals](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Relativistic-Electronic-Structure-Theory-Computational-ebook/dp/B00ESIPMT4/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1509658176&sr=8-1&keywords=Relativistic+Electronic+Structure+Theory+-+Fundamentals) they claim (it refers to quadrupole, octupol and hexadecapole moments):

> As the multipoles are traceless on any two indices, the number of constraints for a multipole of order $n$ is equal to the number $n(n-1)/2$ of index pairs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $i=j$:
$$
\Omega_{iik} \rightarrow 5 \, r_i^2 r_k - r^2 \left( \delta_{ii} r_k + \delta_{ik} r_i + \delta_{ik} r_i \right)
$$
Now, sum over $i$:
$$
\sum_i \Omega_{iik} \rightarrow 5 \, r^2 r_k - r^2 \left( 3 r_k + r_k +r_k\right) = 0
$$

Comment: Sure.  Its probably just a matter of familiarity with these sorts of manipulations.